# Javascript Onload with HTML default value

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<input type="number" min="1" step="0.01" value="1.00" id="price" class="test" onload="divideByFour()" onkeyup="divideByFour()" name="price"><br>

    Across four people, each person (including you) will be billed:

<i><b>&#163;<span style="color:red" id="myspan"></span></b></i>
```

And the javascript function I have is:

```
    function divideByFour() {
        var total = document.getElementById("price").value;
        document.getElementById("myspan").textContent=((total/4).toFixed(2));
    }
```

This function works fine for onkeyup, however for the default value I have when the page is loaded ("value 1.00"), the onload function isn't called. I'm trying to make it such that when the page is loaded, the value displayed in the span is 0.25 (since the default value is 1, and the function divides the value of the input by 4), however nothing is displayed.

Am I using the wrong event for this, or am I missing something to handle default html input values? I've tried both onload and onpageshow and neither worked for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put onLoad attribute in the BODY tag and it should work:

```
<body onload="divideByFour()">
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked that. :D

Comment: no problem... if the answer was useful please accept/upvote

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the initial invocation on an element in the document body. The element may or may not load before your script is evaluated.

Try this instead:

```
function divideByFour() {
    var total = document.getElementById("price").value;
    document.getElementById("myspan").textContent=((total/4).toFixed(2));
}

window.onload = divideByFour;
```